# Editing data inside Ext.XTemplate which is inside Ext.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have to edit data inside my template that is use for Ext.Panel. How can I do this ? I tried to add listener, but click event did not bind click to that panel.

Ext.XTemplate:

```
MyApp.ext.MyExtension.prototype.mytpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<table class="my">',
        '<tr><th>Item:</th><td>{itemIWantToEdit}</td></tr>',
        '</table>',
        '</tpl>'
        ).compile();
```

Ext.Panel:

```
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'east',
                title: 'MyPanel',
                split: true,
                width: 220,
                collapsible: true,
                layout: 'fit'
                // etc...
```

Comment: Are you trying to edit/change the templatecode itself after an instance of the panel has been created?

Comment: After panel has been created, when user clicks that item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the tpl implementation in Ext.Panel you should be able to alter the tpl of an existing Panel by just overwriting the tpl property with a new XTemplate instance.

```
// Create panel
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel(...);

// Later, somewhere else, in a listener for example
myPanel.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for="."> ... </tpl>');
```

Comment: Ok thanx, but how can I add listener to that item in HTML code ?

Comment: What is an 'item'? Are you referring to the `{itemIWantToEdit}` part of your template? In that case i'm inclined to think you should rather use a DataView instead of a Panel with a Template.